# Обработка изображений в Django

Tags: django, изображения, io

Кто может подзсказать? Почему Django при загрузке изображений, некоторые обрабатывает как

django.core.files.temp.TemporaryFile

а другие как

_io.BytesIO

С чем это связано?
Просто, при TemporaryFile django НЕправильно определяет разрешение изображения (он меняет ширину с высотой местами).
Или как сделать, чтобы django определял всегда в одном порядке, т.е. например (ширина, высота)?

Comment: Загрузке изображений куда? Обрабатывает где? Определяет разрешение где? О чём речь вообще? Вы проверяли, что изображения не являются банально повёрнутыми через EXIF?

Comment: @andreymal При загрузке через форму. Я обращаюсь к полученной форме (к полю), там указан атрибут 'file', у этого же поля есть атрибут 'size' (разрешение изображения). Вот некоторые указаны так (ширина, высота), а некоторые (высота, ширина). Хотелось бы, чтобы результат был в одном порядке, например, (ширина, высота)

Comment: Ну вопрос в принципе всё тот же — вы проверяли, что изображения не являются банально повёрнутыми через EXIF?

Comment: @andreymal а как проверить это можно? Я понимаю, что нужно посмотреть метаданные изображения, но на что нужно обратить внимание? Разница между этими изображениями в следующем. Если я сделал фотографию на телефоне (телефонах), и загружаю ее через форму, то она загружается как django.core.files.temp.TemporaryFile, а если я эту же фотографию сохраню через, например, Paint, и загружу, то она загрузиться как _io.BytesIO

Comment: @andreymal я посмотрел метаданные, и разницы не нашел. Или как нужно правильно посмотреть?

Comment: @andreymal да, Вы правы, у них разные Orientation. Есть совет как правильнее обработать ориентацию изображения?